# How to group List<Map<String,Object>> to Map<String,List<Map<String,Object>> in Java8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a `List<Map<String,Object>>`

```
[ {key1: object1a, key2: object2a, key3: object3a}, 
  {key1: object1a, key2: object2a, key3: object3a}, 
  {key1: object1b, key2: object2b, key3: object3b}, 
  {key1: object1b, key2: object2b, key3: object3b}, 
  ...
]
```

and I would like to group it by the third value, to obtain a `Map<String,List<Map<String,Object>>>`:

```
{ object3a: [ {key1: object1a, key2: object2a}, 
              {key1: object1a, key2: object2a}
            ],
  object3b: [ {key1: object1b, key2: object2b}, 
              {key1: object1b, key2: object2b}
            ],
  ...
}
```

Is it possible by using the [`Collectors.groupingBy?`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) method, and how ?

Comment: It isn't really clear to me what you are grouping your data by in your example.

Comment: At first you seemed to be using a JSON-like notation, with lists denoted by `[...]` and maps by `{...}` . . . but then I got to `[sample1: a, sample2 : b]`, and I suddenly have no idea what notation you're using.

Comment: I have a list [{sample1 : a, sample2: b, sample3:c}, {sample1 : b, sample2: d, sample3:c}, ...]. And I would like to group by sample3 : key c by using Collectors.groupingby method to get a map like this { c : [{sample1: a, sample2: b}, {sample1: b, sample2 : d},..]. Is it really possible by using Collectors.groupingby?

Comment: Please write a clear code example.

Comment: @AungSatt I've rewritten your example in a more understandable shape. Please confirm that this is what you want to achieve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The request isn’t a pure grouping operation as you want to modify the elements by removing the grouping value.

If the maps are mutable, it’s still possible and quite easy:

```
List<Map<String,String>> list= …
Map<String,List<Map<String,String>>> map=
  list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m->m.remove("key3")));
```

Note that I use the key `"key3"` here which matches the current revision of the question. To adapt it to your original question, you have to replace `"key3"` with `"sample3"`.